# Are there any chart tools out there?

Tags: trading, mtgox, live-data, tools, charts

Are there any chart tools similar to the ones used in [Forex trading](http://www.dailyfx.com/charts/) available for Bitcoin users? The MtGox Live feed is nice and all, but it doesn't offer the functionality one would expect from a respectable exchange (like a candlestick chart for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slush has made [A bridge](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6019.0) to feed Bitcoin exchange data to [Sierra Chart](http://www.sierrachart.com/).

Of course, if all you want is to look at a candlestick chart (and even if you want a bit more than that), there's always http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Clark Moody's Charts](http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/).